# How to bind the "date" of DatePicker in C#/Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datepicker

How can I bind the "date" of DatePicker from the Silverlight Toolkit correctly? I use the following XAML-Code:

```xml
<sdk:DatePicker 
x:Name="DpDate" 
Width="200" 
Height="25" 
DisplayDate="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

If I pick a Date my ViewModel recieves the changes. But my View doesn't recieve the start value from the ViewModel? Or how can I set the current date?

**Edit**: The "TwoWay"-Binding works with a TextBox in the same View/ViewModel. I think my problem is that I'm not sure what Attribute I should use for the Binding of the DatePicker. Should I use Text, DisplayDate or sth. else?

Comment: Just to clarify. If you set a date in the UI, the variable the Datepicker binds too gets the value. But when the application starts up, the date isnt set to the value in the variable it is binded to?

Answer (score 7):

Try to bind with `SelectedDate`:

```
<sdk:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just bind your `ViewModels` property to Text property of `DatePicker`(to better compatibility use `Converter`).

Also do not forget about implementing  `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `TwoWay` binding Mode

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where the `DatePicker` was bound on `SelectedDate`to a data context containing a child object with a date property. The control would not display changes to the underlying date property. When I added a getter/setter to the data context to update the child object's date, it worked as expected.

This didn't work:

> ```
>  <sdk:DatePicker x:Name="FromDate" SelectedDate="{Binding Child.TheDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
> ```

This worked:

> ```
>  <sdk:DatePicker x:Name="FromDate" SelectedDate="{Binding TheDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
> ```

(This is my first day with WPF/Silverlight so I don't know if there is a better way to solve the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your viewmodel isn't implimenting INotifyPropertyChanged - the binding is in place but the control doesn't know that the property it is bound to has changed.  There are plenty (too many!) examples on web on how to impliment INotifyPropertyChanged [this one](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/08/29/a-base-class-which-implements-inotifypropertychanged/) from JoshSmith is ok.
Alternatively you could make your DateTime property a dependancy property.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from the ViewModel to the View you need to raise the PropertyChanged() event.

[MSDN Article on PropertyChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx)